# Pandas dataframe col - efficient way to change "__" to "_" and "_" to " "?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a column in a dataframe which need replacements made to the contents of the column as follows :

- where a double underbar exists the result should be single underbar
- where a single underbar exists the result should be a space

So for instance `This_is_a_test_and_this_is_what_a_underscore_looks_like__!` should result in `This is a test and this is what a underscore looks like_!`

What I've done so far is the easy bit ...

```
dk['name'].replace({'_': ' '}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

... the only way I can think of to handle both parts of the requirement is to change the double underbars to some other character, say "^", before changing all the single underbars to spaces and then going back to change the "^" to underbars. This doesn't seem like it would be very efficient and presents the problem of the 'magic character' being present initially.

Anyone know of a better way to handle this ?

Comment: I think you are better off splitting this into two separate replace functions as the output of the first replace would interfere with the final output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try `str.replace` with a replacement lambda function

```
d = {'__': '_', '_': ' '}
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'(__|_)', lambda g: d[g.group()])
```

---

```
                                                        name
0  This is a test and this is what a underscore looks like_!
```

Comment: That's beautiful, thanks. I admit that I don't understand how it's working but it does work. I will now go and work out how it does what it does ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dictionary of values to the `replace` method of Series, with regex as `True`.

```py
df['text'].replace({'__':'_', '_':' '}, regex=True)

0    This is a test and this is what a underscore l...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is the output you get with your answer `'This is a test and this is what a underscore looks like !'`